# High end mobile workstations with pointer stick

Tags: laptop, input-devices, kubuntu

I am looking for a list of higher end mobile workstations that run Ubuntu/Kubuntu well and also have a hardware pointer stick.

Here's an illustration of one (from [sciencesurvivalblog](http://www.sciencesurvivalblog.com/wp-content/uploads/ad_files/2010/pointing_stick.jpg)):

[image: laptop pointer/joystick in keyboard]

I wouldn't mind getting a Macbook Pro and wiping it but they refuse to use pointer sticks and to me, they are extremely efficient. I see a lot of potential for Lenovo thinkpads as well. System 76 said they have no plans to implement a hardware pointer stick so that leaves them out as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could ask zaReason.

Comment: OK, so what do you mean by 'higher end mobile workstation' ?

Answer (score 3):

I recently bought an HP Elitebook.  It's a mobile workstation class laptop and it has a pointer that works with Ubuntu.

There are articles on the web detailing Elitebook compatibilities with Ubuntu, (I haven't found support yet for the fingerprint reader). Installing Ubuntu with this computer, as I understand, does not void the manufacturers warranty as with some other laptops.  The warranty (including drop warranty) and services are both superb.  Additionally, the computer comes with Windows XP installed by default and the option to install a Windows 7 Professional provided with CD.

I posted this "unboxing" video on YouTube featuring the Elitebook 8540W.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KePyCr1uAYw&tracker=False

Comment: +1. I got an Elitebook myself, very happy with it. Only thing not working is the fingerprint reader, as stated above. It's got a pointer, I just don't use it cause I prefer the touchpad. Nice touch is having 3 buttons for both touchpad and stick, makes using software which relies heavily on middle-click so much more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Dell Latitude E6510.  I and several of my coworkers are running Ubuntu on it (10.04, 10.10).

We aren't running Kubuntu specifically, but the support for the input hardware should be identical.

Ubuntu integration is great, and it's a pleasure to use.  Fast, tough, and the best-looking Dell I've used. The only important configuration I've had to do manually is settings up the various touchpad/keyboard mouse-click emulation buttons.  (I'm not sure what to call them, but you'll see them on the attached picture.)

I like it better than the System76 system I have that's about the same age. 
Downside is that this one was Windows7 by default.

[image: Dell E6510]